# Politeness When Writing an email

Tags: management, email

I'm facing a bit of a dilemma. Let me explain the situation to you.

- She stated that they would contact me within a short timeframe, when they were waiting to hear back from another company in regards to my security clearance.
- I managed to find out that there was another way to gain this clearance by filling out a form online. (Which I mentioned to her last week)
- She is also an extremely busy person (being a manager).

I was thinking about wording my mail like this:

---

Dear Mrs Stevens,

I just wanted to check with you in regards to the email I sent last week. I understand that you are extremely busy, considering that you are the manager of Company X! If you would like me to, I'd be more than happy to fill out the form I mentioned last week considering you are extremely busy.

I look forward to hearing from you.

Thanks,

Michael.

---

However wouldn't that sound a bit 'rude'? Any other thoughts on how I could word this?

Comment: Are you applying for a job with this company? Also, if they already said that you should fill out the form, why don't you just do it? Alternatively, if you mentioned it already but they *didn't* say that you need to fill out the form, then you probably shouldn't bother them about it a second time.

Comment: Agree with Brandin - if you can fill out the form without their help and then send it to them you'll have shown that you are proactive and not afraid to just step up and do what needs doing.

Comment: See also : [How to wite a polite reminder email](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/how-to-write-a-polite-reminder-email)

Answer (score 3):

No, I would not say this is rude.

However I would change the wording.

> Dear Mrs Stevens,
>
> I just wanted to check with you in regards to the email I sent last week.
>
> I understand that you are extremely busy, considering this I'd be more than
>   happy to fill out the form I mentioned last week, to get my security clearance.
>
> I look forward to hearing from you.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Michael.